# Visual Studio 2019 and Python - Access denied only on .py files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2019

For context, in a work environment with a visual studio 2019 install pushed by central IT.

When trying to open Python scripts to edit them in visual studio (opening from solution explorer), they were opening in notepad instead.

I used "open with" and when selecting the default Python editor, it gives me access denied. This is different to Spyder, in which I can open .py scripts from the file browser with no permissions issues. I checked to see if the security properties of the directory and files within allowed me full access, which they do.

I tried opening one of my .pyw scripts and to my surprise it worked no problem. I then re-named a .py to .pyw and it opened in the visual studio Python editor.

Obviously that is a work around however if anybody has any idea why or solutions that would be great.